# iOS:How could I know UnitTest is testing?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I want to know whether App execute for UnitTest(press CMD+U in Xcode),or execute for running(CMD+r)?

eg:if App run for unit test I fetch data from memory;if it run normally,I fetch data from sqlite DB.

How could I do that?thanks!

Comment: That is what the test itself should do. Do NOT make your app code aware it’s being tested. If you do you’ve ruined the test.

Comment: @matt thanks!but in test I will modify database permanently.and I don’t want add record and delete it everytime test...

Comment: @matt pls reference rails’s test , dev and product 3 env

Comment: @matt I will not change anything in testing except DATA source!

Comment: “pls reference rails’s test , dev and product 3 env” Exactly. The code itself doesn’t change. The test sets the environment. Use refactoring and mocking to structure your code so it can be tested without change. Watch any wwdc vid on this topic.